# How to use `-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard` in swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, lldb

In a project with language Objective-C, I add `-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard` in **Other C Flags** :

[image]

Then I add two methods in project, like belows:

```
void __sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard_init(uint32_t *start, uint32_t *stop) {
  static uint64_t N;  // Counter for the guards.
  if (start == stop || *start) return;  // Initialize only once.
  printf("INIT: %p %p\n", start, stop);
  for (uint32_t *x = start; x < stop; x++)
    *x = ++N;  // Guards should start from 1.
}

void __sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard(uint32_t *guard) {
  if (!*guard) return;
  void *PC = __builtin_return_address(0);
  char PcDescr[1024];
  printf("guard: %p %x PC %s\n", guard, *guard, PcDescr);
}
```

So I can get information that I wanted.

[image]

In `swift` project I also set `Other C Flags`.
And add `-sanitize-coverage=func`、`-sanitize=undefined` in `Other Swift Flags` 
[image]

but I got an error:

```
Undefined symbol: ___sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard_init
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem and get information like `oc` project.

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@michael.eisel/improving-app-performance-with-order-files-c7fff549907f) has inspired me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: I don't think "Other Swift Flags" gets passed to the linker invocation -- that would explain the undefined symbols error. Try adding "-fsanitize=undefined" to the Linker Flags.

Another guess: If you were to pass "-fsanitize=undefined" in the Linker Flags for your ObjC project, you probably wouldn't need to provide your own definitions for __sanitizer_cov_*.